# what is good technique to calculate trending score?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, statistics, data-science

I have 2 items whose purchase counts are as follows.

item1 = 100, 200, 300, 400, 500
item2 = 500, 400, 300, 200, 100

The values are in order day-5, day-4, day-3, day-2, day-1. The last value is the latest.
Though the total counts are same, item1 seems to more trending. I want a technique to calculate the trending score.

I tried using z-score, but couldnt get the right score. I have tried exponential moving weighted average and it is shown below. But it doesnt produce the result I need. Here is the code

```
alpha=0.9
item1_view_counts = [100,200,300,400,500]
item2_view_counts = [500,400,300,200,100]
count_values1 = pd.DataFrame({'count_values': item1_view_counts})
ema1 = count_values1.ewm(alpha=alpha, adjust=True).mean()
sum1 = count_values1.ewm(alpha=alpha, adjust=True).mean().tail(5).sum()
count_values2 = pd.DataFrame({'count_values': item2_view_counts})
ema2 = count_values2.ewm(alpha=alpha, adjust=True).mean()
sum2 = count_values2.ewm(alpha=alpha, adjust=True).mean().tail(5).sum()
print("ema1:" + str(ema1))
print("ema2:" + str(ema2))
print("score1:" + str(sum1))
print("score2:" + str(sum2))
```

Result

```
ema1:   count_values
0    100.000000
1    190.909091
2    289.189189
3    388.928893
4    488.893889
ema2:   count_values
0    500.000000
1    409.090909
2    310.810811
3    211.071107
4    111.106111
score1:count_values    1457.921062
dtype: float64
score2:count_values    1542.078938
dtype: float64
```

I am looking for some technique that scores the item1 higher than item2.

Appreciate your help here.

Comment: ema1 is strictly increasing, ema2 isnt, I dont think I get your question.

Comment: I want a score or some thing that tells item1 is more trending than item1. I am taking a sum of ema values as score here

Comment: @LijjuMathew How do you define "trending"?

Comment: In the example above the sum of purchase counts are same, but item1 has a upward trend and item2 has a downward trend. I am looking to calculate a score that takes into account the upward trend and downward trend.

Answer (score 0):

There are time series models that can give you trend as an attribute.
For something simple and quick, I computed average delta between current and previous time period.

```
df['item1_shifted'] = df['item1'].shift()
df['item1_change'] = df['item1'] - df['item1_shifted']

df['item2_shifted'] = df['item2'].shift()
df['item2_change'] = df['item2'] - df['item2_shifted']

df[['item1_change','item2_change']].mean() gives :  100, -100
```

[image]